# QObject::connect: signal not found in promoted widget with Lambda syntax

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, signals-slots

I have an overloaded QTreeWidget class, with my SIGNALS: I have promoted it in my UI and when I listen promoted QTreeWidget object with a lambda syntax I have an error.

```
QObject::connect: signal not found in CustomTreeWidget.
```

MY CustomTreeWidget looks like:

**.h**

```
class CustomTreeWidget : public QTreeWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CustomTreeWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~CustomTreeWidget() {
    }

signals:
    void currentNodeChanged(QSet<int> uids);
    void deleteRequest(QVector<int> uids);
}
```

**.cpp**

```
CustomTreeWidget::CustomTreeWidget(QWidget *parent) : QTreeWidget(parent)
{
    setAnimated(true);

    connect(this, &CustomTreeWidget::customContextMenuRequested, this, [=](const QPoint &pos) {
        this->m_bCustomMenuOpen = true;
        const auto &&item = this->itemAt(pos);

        QMenu myMenu;

        bool ok = !(item) ? false : true;

        if (ok) {
        //თუ topLevelItem -ია მხოლოდ დამატების action -ი უნდა იყოს ჩართული.
            if (item == this->topLevelItem(0) || item == this->topLevelItem(0)->child(0)) {
                ok = false;
            }
        }

        QAction *Removecnt = myMenu.addAction(tr("&წაშლა"), this, SLOT(DeleteNode()));
        Removecnt->setIcon(QIcon(":/global_res/delete.png"));
        Removecnt->setEnabled(ok);

        myMenu.exec(this->mapToGlobal(pos));
    });
}

void CustomTreeWidget::BFS(QTreeWidgetItem *item, QSet<int> &out)
{
    std::queue<QTreeWidgetItem *> Q;
    Q.push(item);

    while (!Q.empty()) {
        QTreeWidgetItem *now = Q.front(); Q.pop();
        out.insert(this->m_mapUids[now]);
        for (int i = 0; i < now->childCount(); i++) {
            Q.push(now->child(i));
        }
    }
}

QSet<int> CustomTreeWidget::GetCurrentNodeUids()
{
    QSet<int> uids;
    if (!this->currentItem())
        return uids;

    this->BFS(this->currentItem(), uids);
    return uids;
}

void CustomTreeWidget::DeleteNode()
{
    QSet<int> nodes = this->GetCurrentNodeUids();
    QVector<int> uids;
    for (auto it : nodes) {
        uids.push_back(it);
    }

    emit deleteRequest(uids);
}
```

My lambda looks like:

```
connect(ui->productTree, &CustomTreeWidget::deleteRequest, this, [=](QVector<int> uids) {
    //logic
});
```

But this signal works with old syntax.

```
connect(ui->productTree, SIGNAL(deleteRequest(QVector<int>)), this, SLOT(checkSlot(QVector<int>)));
```

And this slot is.

```
void ProductForm::checkSlot(QVector<int> uids)
{
    qDebug() << uids.size();
}
```

So what is problem lambda syntax?

Comment: Are you sure, the error you write about is related to new syntax? It looks like error at runtime when you use old syntax.

Comment: Yes i am sure. The error i have in a runtime if i using new syntax. But old syntax everything okay.

Comment: It might be context issue. Does it work if you change lambda to capture `this` and/or a `tree` object, as so: `[this]` or `[this, ui->productTree]`?

Comment: @Bobur When i change [=] to [this] everything is same, when i change = [this, ui->productTree] i have excepted before token ';'

Comment: @iLoveTatiaGaruchava 
For me your code works correctly, try removing the build folder. To test your code I had to patch it so it would help a lot if you publish a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This smells like the violation of the one definition rule (ODR) - perhaps due to a stale build folder. The problem is that the address of `deleteRequest` passed to the `connect` method is not the same as the address of the method visible from `moc_CustomTreeWidget.cpp`. Remove the build folder and try again. If it still doesn't work, start reducing your problem:

1. Create a minimization branch in the repository (if you're not using version control, you won't go anywhere with minimization).
2. Copy-paste the contents of the `ui_CustomTreeWidget.h` file into the `CustomTreeWidget.cpp` file, remove the `#include` line.
3. Inspect the pasted contents for instantiation of the `productTree` object with the correct type.
4. If that's correct, then remove everything else from the code, step-by-step, rebuilding and committing to the repository at each step that still reproduces. You should end up with a test case that is 20-30 lines long at most. And it'll be either obvious what's wrong, or you can modify the question with the test case.

Comment: I am try remove build project and rebuild but have a same situation. While I start a reducing just a curious i have a question.. I dont know why but my CustomTreeWidget class have a UI. Should it be? :D

Comment: I removed UI, also cleaned, ran qmake rebuild but everything is the same... I created a test project and it works... I dont mind what happends.

Comment: Start with a *clean* source folder. That means: make a fresh clone/working copy of your source repository, then open it up in the IDE, cofnigure a build, and build.